# Command to open "Configure advanced user profile properties" (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-7

I'm trying to figure out how to open the "Configure advanced user profile properties" control panel window by command line, so that I can provide a link to it in my application.

It can be opened without going through the control panel by typing "userprofile" in Start->Search box. So I assume that it must have a valid command to open it directly, but I can't seem to figure out what the command is.

I've found that "control nusrmgr.cpl" opens the control panel for "User Accounts" which has the link to "Configure advanced user profile properties", but I want to provide a direct link.

Anyone have any insight to how this can be done?

Comment: In Windows 10, this is `control.exe userpasswords`, you can even create a shortcut to that. You can consider [this very useful list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Panel_(Windows)#Standard_applets)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The actual command line for `Configure advanced user profile properties` is:
`rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditUserProfiles`. You can just copy & paste this into cmd window to run.

**Further reading:** [Entry for `run` at ss64.com](https://archive.is/EMb0j#selection-1805.20-1805.59)

Comment: this is not working for me unfortunately ( i don't get any window)

Comment: @JessStone What OS version? What user privileges? I just run it on Win 7 [64bit] as Admin and it shows

Comment: I apologize, just tried again right now, and it worked! thanks

Comment: Is there an option to open the virtual memory settings page too?

Comment: @RoYoMi It's been a long time since I've written this... but I don't think there is a single command to do this. Closest I found is `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` (see more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191(v=vs.85).aspx)). What you try to accomplish? Maybe there is another way of getting the result you need?

Comment: @wmz We have a system admin's nightmare where every server is a unique and delicate snowflake. I have commands that will automatically adjust the Page file settings, but with every computer being unique scripting this is proving to be more difficult than just popping open the GUI. I was hoping to find the raw command that directly opens up the page file settings gui without having to click through a maze of buttons.

Answer (score 1):

For others that find themselves here: [the answer provided by @wmz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12587748/4575793) still works for me, Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit, 21H1. This page was the first result when I Googled for this question/solution.

Running this from a standard command prompt will produce a non-elevated version of this applet (with only your current profile listed). Running from an Admin command prompt will produce the elevated version (with all profiles listed). Also, for me it takes several seconds to load and does not indicate that it is loading, but does still load.

> The actual command line for Configure advanced user profile properties is:
> rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditUserProfiles. You can just copy & paste this into cmd window to run.
>
> Further reading: [Entry for `run` at ss64.com](https://archive.is/EMb0j#selection-1805.20-1805.59)